# How does the Buffer app append UTM parameters?

Tags: url, buffer

[Buffer](https://bufferapp.com/) seems like a great way to link multiple social accounts and conveniently crosspost. There's plenty of praise on the web for the service, it seems super user friendly, and it looks like it might be the right app for my use case.

But one thing I can't readily find on the net: **How does Buffer add UTM parameters?**

A screenshot:

[image: How does Buffer add UTM parameters]

What UTM convention does Buffer use? And is there any way to customize this scheme for our particular purposes?

Comment: it's custom code behind the option.

Comment: @Sathya Not quite sure what you mean. Any chance you can elaborate?

Comment: I meant it's flipswitch that makes Buffer add on the UTM parameters at their server side code, there are no user facing changes that can be done (wrt: customize the scheme)

Comment: Looks like Buffer just updated the way they handle UTMs. See the blog post: http://blog.bufferapp.com/introducing-google-analytics-integration-for-buffer-and-3-more-features

Answer (score 3):

Enabling UTM parameters in standard (free) Buffer creates URLs tagged with the following convention:

**http://foo.com/?utm_content=buffer[content ID]&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=[twitter or facebook or ...]&utm_campaign=Buffer**

These URLs are then shortened with the buff.ly shortener.

On Jan 9, [Buffer announced](http://blog.bufferapp.com/introducing-google-analytics-integration-for-buffer-and-3-more-features) UTM customization for Buffer for Business customers. Paying customers can now enter custom Campaign, Source & Medium parameters (but not Content). This feature is available at the Settings → Link Shortening page.

[image]

Hitting "Customize Campaign Tracking" opens this menu:

[image]